# Why I can not find the FileInfo?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I already add this two :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

In my code but still can not find the `FileInfo` Class. When I build my project. Error given below :

> 'FileInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I tried to use the class with full name `System.IO.FileInfo` , also Error:

> 'System.IO.FileInfo' could be not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

It also do not have the File Class in the System.IO namespace

System.IO contains something like `Path`, `BinaryReader/Writer`, `StreamReader/Writer`

I use .Net 4.5 in VS 2012 to develop some Win8 app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to include what programming language you are using as a tag, it helps direct the question to the right group of people!

Comment: The FileInfo class is not available in a Store app.  It isn't clear what you are trying to do, and is likely to be inappropriate in a Store app, start with the StorageFolder class.

Comment: Hans.. that would make a great answer ;)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060697/how-to-get-a-file-using-winrt  Possible Dup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans Passant said on comments `FileInfo` class is not available in a Windows Store Apps.

Apps created with C#/XAML do use the .NET Framework, but only a subset named [.NET API for Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx). You can access the `System.IO` on the Windows Store Apps, but you do not have all classes you had on .Net Framework.

Take a look:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454050.aspx

So, you can use the `StorageFile` class. Take a look at this sample:
http://metroapps.wikispaces.com/File+IO

Comment: Thanks, also poke & Hans Passant's answer helps a lot.

Comment: Just to correct a bit: Windows Store Apps created with C#/XAML do use the .NET Framework, but only a subset named ".NET API for Windows Store Apps". .NET API for Windows Store Apps is defined by reference assemblies. Windows Store Apps even use the CLR to execute the .NET code.

Answer (score 3):

As Hans Passant correctly said, [`System.IO.FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) is not available for Windows Store applications. You can see which types are available for the store by looking for the store icon [image: store icon] in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29kt2zfk.aspx) listings.